# Как сделать так, чтобы программа работала с любыми данными и соответствовала условию задачи?

Tags: javascript

Ребят, очень нужна ваша помощь в решении задачки на JS. Я являюсь абсолютным новичком и учу JS всего пару недель, поэтому кому-то задачка точно покажется легкой. В общем, условие такое:

> Машина едет по участку дороги, где некоторые участки дороги могут быть повреждены.
> Участок дороги задается в виде массива «roadWithDamages» из десяти логических элементов.
> Если элемент внутри массива имеет значение - true, значит участок дороги поврежден.
> Поездка машины должна быть реализована в виде цикла, где каждая итерация — один шаг вперед (типа следующий элемент массива).
> После каждого шага функция должна выдавать в консоль "Машина переходит к шагу ${i + 1}".
> Если автомобиль натыкается на повреждение (логическое значение - true):
>
> - в первый раз в консоли должно быть написано "Машина повреждена", но мы можем продолжить переход к следующему шагу
> - во второй раз в консоли пишет "Машина сломана" и переход к следующему шагу не происходит.

Пример вывода консоли:

```
moveCar([false, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]);

Машина переходит к шагу 1
Машина переходит к шагу 2
Машина переходит к шагу 3
Машина переходит к шагу 4
Машина повреждена
Машина переходит к шагу 6
Машина сломана
```

Вот моя попытка решения:

```
let roadWithDamages = [true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false];
for (let i = 0; i < roadWithDamages.length; i++) {

    if (i == 4) console.log('The car is damaged');
    if (i == 4) continue;
    if (i == 6) console.log('The car is broken');
    if (i == 6) break;

    console.log (`The car goes to step ${i + 1}`)
}
```

Сказали, что плохо и что надо, чтоб работало с любыми данными. В общем, ребят, идей больше никаких нет. Прошу о помощи!

Comment: внутри цикла у вас должен быть условный оператор для проверки значения текущего элемент массива. Также надо завести счетчик плохих учатстков. Если в массиве встречается true, то надо увеличить счетчик. И тут же проверем значение этого счетчика, если 1 то одно сообщение, если 2, то второе и выход из цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом алгоритм прост.

- `maxDamageCounter` - счетчик максимального количества повреждений авто.
- `damageCounter` - количество повреждений.

А дальше простой счетчик.

```js
const roadWithDamages = [true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false];

const maxDamageCounter = 2;
let damageCounter = 0;

for (let step = 0; step < roadWithDamages.length; step++) {
  const road = roadWithDamages[step];
  if (damageCounter < maxDamageCounter) {
    if (road) {
      damageCounter++;
      if (damageCounter >= maxDamageCounter){
        console.log('Машина сломана!');
        break;
      }
      console.log('Машина повреждена');
    } else {
      console.log(`Машина переходит к шагу ${step + 1}`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Машина сломана!');
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за помощь! Буквально 1 уточнение еще бы хотела узнать. У меня в конзоле выходит Машина переходит к шагу 1  Машина переходит к шагу 2 Машина переходит к шагу 3 Машина переходит к шагу 4 Машина повреждена Машина переходит к шагу 6  Машина повреждена Машина сломана! Каким образом мне убрать предпоследнее предложение, где Машина повреждена? Хотелось бы, чтоб после Машина переходит к шагу 6 было только Машина сломана! и все

Comment: Поправил ответ. Теперь делает так, как вы и хотели.

Comment: SaNFeeD, большое спасибо вам за помощь. Но почему-то когда пробую исполнить код, дает мне теперь такой результат, Машина повреждена
Машина переходит к шагу 2
Машина переходит к шагу 3
Машина переходит к шагу 4
Машина сломана!
А необходимый результат нужен такой- Машина переходит к шагу 1
Машина переходит к шагу 2
Машина переходит к шагу 3
Машина переходит к шагу 4
Машина повреждена
Машина переходит к шагу 6
Машина сломана! 
Есть предположение, что где-то еще надо вставить еще 1 if. Так ли это?

Comment: Все, я вкурила, в чем была шайза. В самой первой строке там было написано [true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false];, а нужно было const roadWithDamages = [false, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]; и теперь все как нужно, благодарю за помощь еще раз!

Comment: Рад был помочь! Удачи в ваших начинаниях.